# Can not understand this scale bitmap code

Tags: android, bitmap

In one of the tutorials Google proposes the following scaling bitmap algorithm to make a bitmap fit a given window:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

( http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html )

I don't understand the `if(width > height)` part

Suppose a bitmap has its height of 5 and its width of 2. Then suppose  a window has the height of 1 and the width of 1. It looks like the bitmap won't fit the window then.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sure that the size ratio is respected